# div not extending to bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout like this-

[image]
Footer is sticky.

Below is the code I tried:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -45px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fdbb30;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.adminpanelContainer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#footerwrapper {
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="panelContainer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container" id="footerwrapper"></div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I am giving `height: 100%` to `.adminpanelContainer` and its ancestors also but there is no effect on it.

I want the white area to expand across the whole web page irrespective of their height.

What changes I have to make to extend the `div` till bottom.

Answer (score 1):

**This will work for you:**

I have just added ↓

```
#body .container{
  height: calc(100vh - (90px + 45px));
}
```

the calculation is as follows:

```
height: calc(100ViewportHeight - (#header[height+padding-bottom]+ #footerwrapper[height]));
```

If you want to learn more about [**`calc`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [**`vh`**](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), please click on them.

*A working Sample from your snippet:*

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -45px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fdbb30;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.adminpanelContainer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#footerwrapper {
  height: 45px;
}

#body .container{
  height: calc(100vh - (90px + 45px));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="container" >
        <div class="panelContainer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container" id="footerwrapper">

    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without adjusting any existing markup the intended behaviour can be achieved by declaring `<percentage>` height unit values for applicable nested elements as well.

1. Start by declaring a relative height (with *percentage unit values*)
   for the element `#body` - account for the combined `height` of the
   nested `header` & `footer` elements, e.g:

   ```
   #body {
       /* 100% height minus the sum of header & footer height */
       height: calc(100% - 125px);
   }
   ```
2. Next, declare `height: 100%` for any further nested elements that
   are required to occupy the full *available height* of the viewport,
   e.g:

   ```
   .panelContainer {
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```

The code snippets below demonstrate this behaviour with both `fixed` and `relative` footer elements.

**Fixed Footer:**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-wrap { /* adjusted */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fdbb30;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.adminpanelContainer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* additional */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footerwrapper {
  height: 45px;
}

/* Additional */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#body {
    height: calc(100% - 125px); /* 100% height minus the sum of header & footer height */
}

.panelContainer {
    height: 100%;
    /* following styles added just for the sake of demonstration */
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.panelContainer .inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.panelContainer .inner span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <span>height: 80px</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="panelContainer">
          <div class="inner"><span>relative height declared with <code>percentage</code> values</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container" id="footerwrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <span>height: 45px</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**Relative Footer:**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-wrap { /* adjusted */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fdbb30;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.adminpanelContainer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* additional */
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footerwrapper {
  height: 45px;
}

/* Additional */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#body {
    height: calc(100% - 80px); /* 100% height minus the height of the header */
}

.panelContainer {
    height: 100%;
    /* following styles added just for the sake of demonstration */
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.panelContainer .inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.panelContainer .inner span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <span>height: 80px</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
      <div class="container" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="panelContainer">
          <div class="inner"><span>relative height declared with <code>percentage</code> values</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container" id="footerwrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <span>height: 45px</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**Practical Interactive CodePen Demonstrations:**

Here you can observe practical demonstrations, for `fixed` and `relative` footers, which allow content to be added or removed dynamically. In addition, these demonstrations *also account for dynamic footer heights*.

1. [Keeping a Fixed Footer at the bottom of page (Dynamic Footer Height)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/ooxmMQ)
2. [Keeping a Relative Footer at the bottom of page (Dynamic Footer
   Height)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/KyzJZg)